# Defining local variables within partial templates using AJAX / Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I have a deeply nested partial view, where I iterate over a collection of `@users`.  The controller defines the `@users` like so:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

def following
  @users = @user.followed_users
  ..
end
```

In the partial templates, I iterate over the collection, but I never define the individual of a collection as an instance variable, instead I pass the local variables along with `:object`:

```
<% if current_user.following?(user) %>
  <%= render partial: 'unfollow', object: user, as: :user %>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: 'follow', object: user, as: :user %>
<% end %>
```

Problem is...

Inside the `create.js.erb` file that handles the **Follow** action, for example, I use the following code:

```
$('#follow_form').html("<%=j render partial: 'users/unfollow', object: user, as: :user %>");
```

This gives me the following errors from my dev log:

**ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#:0x007fa17b9e57e0>):**

Am I declaring the partial wrong in jQuery?  Do I have to define `user` somewhere else, like in the controller?  If so **how do I define an individual of a collection as an instance variable**?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT: Included associated controller**

Here is the associated controller that handles the request:

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

def create
debugger
@user = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
current_user.follow!(@user)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to @user }
  format.js
end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it seems the user variable is not defined. In the controller code where you follow the user, assign that user to a @user variable, then use that instead of user in create.js.erb

Comment: @Dipil in the controller, i have a variable `@users`, then i iterate over them in my view.  I'm not sure how to properly assign an instance variable to individuals of a collection

Comment: can you add the backtrace for the exception so the error can be traced back..

Comment: Where is `create.js.erb` being used? Presumably not from the `following` method in your controller, right? More likely it's part of a `create` method. So you need to use the instance variable _that_ action is creating.

Comment: @Dipil the backtrace points to the `relationships_controller` (now included) where the `respond_to` block begins

Comment: @rfunduk thanks for the response, you're right, the `create` method is in the `relationships_controller` (now included above).  Problem is, I'm not sure how to identify the instance variable since I am iterating over a collection.  Maybe I can pass the local variable `user` to `@user` in the controller?  I'll try.

Comment: pruett the create.js.erb view only has access to the variables defined in the create action. So, I think simply using @user instead of user in create.js.erb will solve your problem here.

Comment: @Dipil you're 100% right...thanks so much!!  I'm still trying to figure out the flow of the actions and why this works, but you helped me a ton.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dipil helped me out with the simple solution of replacing the local variable `user` with the instance variable `@user` set in the controller.  This worked perfectly.

Final output after some minor refactoring:

```
$("#follow_form").html("<%=j render partial: 'users/unfollow', locals: { user: @user } %>");
```